# Can I merge 2 Apple ID/iTunes accounts then change 1 to a teen account

Tags: itunes, icloud, email, apple-id, macos

Finally making the switch from Android to Apple. Never before an Apple user. My daughter uses one of my old email addresses for her iTunes and Apple ID account, she is 14. I stay logged onto that email for her iTunes account and some of my other contacts. Unlike previous questions on here, I do not want to create a new child account, because from what I've read apps and items purchased will not transfer. I want to know if I create a new Apple ID / iTunes account using a new email can I connect or merge the two accounts and change hers to a child/teen account? If so, how? If not, any advice or thoughts on what I should do or not do? Should I just leave it as is and monitor her account as usual? I do not want her to loose all her purchases.

Comment: Your daughter will want to get a new account - she will not want you being able to read here email as she gets older. (At 14 I am surprised she does not like it now)  So now might be the time to seperate your old account and hers.

Comment: Thank you. But let me clarify,  I don’t/can’t monitor her emails. Her Apple ID uses my email address to log in, the only thing  that I know of that I can do is view are her purchases, since I do not have her Apple ID password. She has her own email now. When we set up her 1st iPod when she was 8, she didn’t have an email to use for her iTunes account. When got older and got her 1st phone (an iPhone) she used the same iTunes account to set up her Apple ID. She has since set up her own email.

Comment: I think you are confusing email addresses with actual Apple IDs. The email address itself is not the ID, but you cannot re-use an existing email address that is linked to an existing Apple ID for any new Apple ID. One of you must have a new ID, then you can set up family sharing to link purchases. Whoever gets the new ID loses all access to the other ID's data, but not its purchases.

Comment: I think I kinda understand, but am explaining it wrong or confusing. She used my old email address to create her Apple ID. So her Apple ID is linked to my old email address. When I just purchased my IPhone, I used my new email address to create my Apple ID. If that helps clear that part up a bit. I have been very busy transferring all my android stuff to my new iPhone so I haven’t really looked too much further into this, but really appreciate everyone’s help and advise.

Comment: So you set up a new Apple ID with your new email address. Set that up as the Family sharing 'organsier' (& payer;). Invite your daughter's account as a child account. See https://support.apple.com/HT201060 for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Apple IDs cannot be merged.

You can add an existing account to a family sharing group. Purchases made by any account will be available to everyone in the group, so no purchases will be lost.

Comment: I found this - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6543361 on dropping an adult account to a child account. I've no real way to test it, but perhaps that way the new account could become organiser & only adult, with the existing one dropped to child status.

Comment: Additionally - though no apps will be lost,. one person is going to get all the Contacts data, game progress etc & the other is going to get a clean slate.